# Dividing 4 married couples into pairs

Tags: probability

4 married couples arrived at a party.

The 8 people were divided randomly into pairs.

A) What is the probability of the event in which each man found himself with his wife?

B) What is the probability that each pair contains a man and a woman?

For A I'm thinking maybe: ((2!)^4)*(4!)/8!

For B I don't have any idea for now.

Thank you

Comment: Your guess for A) is (far) greater than $1$. That is a dead giveaway of a wrong result in probability.

Comment: I fixed it. is that god now? or should i add another thing?

Comment: The number seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H_1,W_1,H_2,W_2,H_3,W_3,H_4,W_4$ be the eight people.

We generate the pairs by arranging them along a line and then by taking as a first pair the first person and the second person, as a second pair the third and the fourth and so on.

As regards A, we have $8!$ total arrangements. 
Favourable cases: we permute the couples in $4!$ ways and there are $2^4$ possible swappings husband-wife:
$$p_A=\frac{2^4\cdot 4!}{8!}=\frac{1}{105}.$$

As regards B, we have $8!$ total arrangements. Favourable cases: we permute the husbands in $4!$ ways, the wifes in $4!$ and there are  $2^4$  possible swappings husband-wife:
$$p_B=\frac{2^4\cdot 4!\cdot 4!}{8!}=\frac{24}{105}=\frac{8}{35}.$$

Comment: are you saying that there are $8!$ ways of dividing $8$ people into pairs?

Comment: @user259242 I'm agree with you, i think it supposed to be 8!/((2!)^4)

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: @user259242 I am considering ordered pairs. Here we are interested in the probability.

Comment: @RobertZ You're right, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to calculate it: order the people in any way. First you choose a pair for the first person, which you can do in seven ways. Then you choose one for the second (which is the next in line not paired), which can be done in five ways, and so on. Thanks to the ordering, no pairing will be counted twice.

In total, there are $7\cdot 5\cdot 3\cdot 1=105$ pairings. Since there is exactly one pairing which keeps married couples together, the probability of that happening is $105^{-1}$.

Now, if you want to pair men with women, simply chose a man for each woman in order, so you have $4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1=24$ such pairings, so the probability comes as $24/105=8/35$. (Note that the results are consistent with the ones obtained by Robert Z.)

Answer (score 0):

There are $\frac1{4!}\binom8{2,2,2,2}=\frac{8!}{4!2!2!2!2!}=105$ ways to split up in pairs.

Observe that there are $\binom82$ ways to choose the first couple. Then $\binom62$ to choose the second, et cetera. That gives $\binom82\binom62\binom42\binom22=\binom8{2,2,2,2}$ possibilities. However, this counts every way to split up in pairs $4!$ times, so needs to be repaired.

---

A) $1$ of these results in this event, leading to $p_A=\frac1{105}$.

B) $4!$ of these result in this event, leading to $p_B=\frac{24}{105}=\frac8{35}$.

Answer (score 0):

I see it in a different way (using conditional probability), with the same results:

**A)** You choose 2 persons in each step. In the 1st step, you can choose one of the four "correct" pairs, and have $\binom{8}{2}$ possibilities to do that. So the probability to choose a "correct" pair is $\frac{4}{\binom{8}{2}}$. In the second step, you have 3 "correct" pairs left, i.e. 3 favourable outcomes, and $\binom{6}{2}$ possibilities, so the probability to choose a "correct" pair is $\frac{3}{\binom{6}{2}}$. In the 3rd step, following the same arguments, the probability to choose a "correct" pair is $\frac{2}{\binom{4}{2}}$. Then, in the last step, there is only the favourable possibility left, with probability 1. it follows that $$p_A=\frac{4}{\binom{8}{2}} \cdot \frac{3}{\binom{6}{2}} \cdot \frac{2}{\binom{4}{2}} \cdot 1 = \frac{1}{105}$$

**B)** Use hypergeometric distribution (think of the urn model with 4 white and 4 black balls). For the first pair, I have to choose one of the 4 men, one of the four woman, when to choose 2 of 8 in total. The probability of choosing that is $\frac{\binom{4}{1} \cdot \binom{4}{1}}{\binom{8}{2}}$. In the 2nd step. I have to choose 1 of the remaining 3 men, 1 of the remaining 3 woman, when to choose 2 out of 6 in total. Probability is $\frac{\binom{3}{1} \cdot \binom{3}{1}}{\binom{6}{2}}$. 3rd and 4th step follow the same arguments. Finally, we get $$p_B=\frac{\binom{4}{1} \cdot \binom{4}{1}}{\binom{8}{2}} \cdot \frac{\binom{3}{1} \cdot \binom{3}{1}}{\binom{6}{2}} \cdot \frac{\binom{2}{1} \cdot \binom{2}{1}}{\binom{4}{2}}\cdot 1=\frac{8}{35}$$